# List of Tox-supported tools

Tags: python, mypy, tox, flake8

How can I know if tox offer support for a specific tool?

To be specific, I'd like to know why this tox.ini section works for flake8:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 120 # works like a charm

[testenv:flake8]
deps = flake8    
commands = flake8 mypackage/
```

and this one does not for mypy:

```
[mypy]
ignore-missing-imports = True # won't be taken into account

[testenv:mypy]
deps = mypy
commands = mypy mypackage/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `tox` support, it's tools support (or not). For example, `flake8` can [read its settings from `tox.ini`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations) and [`mypy` doesn't](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html).

There is no an exhaustive list of what tools read `tox.ini` and which don't. You have to read the docs for every tool separately.